# QGis 3.4 Categorized Symbology: Overlapping objects

Tags: symbology, overlapping-features, qgis-3

I have a point layer with categorized symbology

One object is a big point and one is a smaller one.

How do I change which one is displayed in front of the other one?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In you layers `style`-tab, click at the bottom right on `extended`, from the opening drop down menu choose `symbol layers`. Check the checkbox, then change the symbol layer of the small point to something other than `0`. Now the small point should be displayed always on top of the large one.[image]